# Application to monitor remote servers for ssh connections?

Tags: monitoring

Is there an application that runs on either windows or linux that will monitor remote linux servers for SSH, and FTP connections and display a notice whenever a user is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a monitoring software like nagios to monitor your server. If you could not find a plugin to do what you want, you can write your own script to check when a user is connected. A command like `w` or `who` will be useful to you.

Comment: Nagios is great for monitoring services but doesn't show me who's logging on to my servers. If I wanted to have a custom script made i'd post to odesk. I'm hoping there's an application already built that can do this.

Comment: The checking plugin/script can provide the needed information not only the service status!

Comment: Would you please post a link to the checking plugin

Comment: I am not talking about specific plugin. You can search for a one or write your own.

Answer (score 1):

If remote server is linux and if scalability is not an issue, this could be done on the remote side

Install Gmail notifier on your desktop

For SSH
 Add this line under Debian to your "/etc/bash.bashrc"
>

> > echo 'Login on' `hostname` `date` `who`| mail -s "Login on `hostname` who | awk '{print $5}'`" name@gmail.com

For FTP
If you are using ProFTPd (default Debian ftp server) you can use ftpmail http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/ftpmail.html that monitors transfer log.

Comment: Hi Sergei, very cool idea to use Gmail notifier, since it's only a few servers right now that's not a problem. I use vsftpd on my servers I don't think it has that built in but can maybe monitor the vsftp.log

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/)  Then setup a filter to monitor your ssh auth log for certain users/stations/etc.